# tensorflow two matrix elementwise multiply in axis = 0, (M,k) * (M,l) --> (M,k*l)

Tags: tensorflow, elementwise-operations

I have a two matrix, F(shape = (4000, 64)) and M(shape=(4000,9))
and want to have result that have shape = (4000,64*9)

i can think with for loop with below code(ideal)

```
result = np.zeros(4000,64*9)
ind = 0
for i in range(64):
    for j in range(9):
        result[:,ind]= tf.muliply(F[:,i]),M[:,j])
        ind += 1
```

but i know For Loop is not support in tensorflow

Is there a function that performs the same function as above code?

---

edit)

I came up with an idea. F,M repeat to shape (4000,64*9) [liek repmat in MATLAB] and elementwise multiply.
Could you ever have any other ideas?

Comment: are you sure this would work? Would not `tf.muliply(F[:,i]),M[:,j])` try to multiply two `4000x1` matrices?

Comment: @SalvadorDali  i know tf.multiply is elementwise multiply in tensorflow

Comment: oh, sorry. I somehow missed the word 'elementwise' in your question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
tf.reshape(M[:,tf.newaxis,:] * F[...,tf.newaxis], [4000,-1])
```

Comment: thank you, and i test it, a= np.arnage(9).reshape(3,3), b=np.array([10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22]).reshape(3,2), F=tf.constant(a), M= tf.constant(b), temp= tf.reshape(M[:,tf.newaxis,:]*F[..., tf.mewaxis], [3, -1]) and sess.run and get result all -1. why don't operate correctly?

Comment: i run anther computer and get correct values. maybe my laptop problem thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tf.matmul` if you reshape your inputs to `F(shape = (4000, 64, 1))` and  `M(shape=(4000,1, 9))`. An example,

```
F = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=(4000, 64, 1)))
M = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=(4000, 1, 9)))
C = tf.matmul(F, M)
C = tf.reshape(C, (4000, -1))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print(C.eval().shape)

#Output: (4000, 576)
```